# C++ Mandelbrot program won't produce correct output

Tags: c++, mandelbrot

I am trying to make a program that generates an image of the standard Mandelbrot set by making a .PPM file. The program doesn't produce a valid PPM file and I have no clue why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
For each pixel (Px, Py) on the screen, do:
{
    x0 = scaled x coordinate of pixel (scaled to lie in the Mandelbrot X scale (-2.5, 1))
    y0 = scaled y coordinate of pixel (scaled to lie in the Mandelbrot Y scale (-1, 1))
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0
    iteration = 0
    max_iteration = 1000
    while ( x*x + y*y < 2*2  AND  iteration < max_iteration )
    {
        xtemp = x*x - y*y + x0
        y = 2*x*y + y0
        x = xtemp
        iteration = iteration + 1
    }
    color = palette[iteration]
    plot(Px, Py, color)
}
*/

int findMandelBrot(double cr, double ci, int max_iterations){
    int i = 0;
    double zr = 0.0, zi = 0.0;
    while (i > max_iterations && zr * zr + zi * zi < 4.0){
        double temp = zr * zr - zi * zi;
        zi = 2.0 * zr * zi + ci;
        zr = temp;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

double mapToReal(int x, int imageWidth, double minR, double maxR){
    double range = maxR - minR;

    return x * (range / imageWidth) + minR;
}

double mapToImaginary(int y, int imageWidth, double minI, double maxI){
    double range = maxI - minI;

    return y * (range / imageWidth) + minI;

}

int main(){

ifstream fin;
fin.open ("input.txt");
int imageWidth, imageHeight, maxN;
double minR, maxR, minI, maxI;

if (!fin.is_open()){
    cerr << "Couldn't load input.txt file" << endl;
    return 0;
}

fin >> imageWidth >> imageHeight >> maxN;
fin >> minR >> maxR >> minI >> maxI;
fin.close();

ofstream fout("output_image.ppm");
fout << "P3" << endl; 
fout << imageWidth << " " << imageHeight;
fout << "256" << endl;

for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++){
        double cr = mapToReal(x, imageWidth, minR, maxR);
        double ci = mapToImaginary(y, imageHeight, minI, maxI);

        int n = findMandelBrot(cr, ci, maxN);

        int r = (n % 256);
        int g = (n % 256);
        int b = (n % 256);

        fout << r << " " << g << " " << b << " ";
    }
    fout.close();
}
fout.close();
cout << "Finished! " << endl;

cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give an example input file.

Comment: Don't think your output quite conforms to the PPM specification, see http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

Comment: What is telling you that it isn't a valid PPM file?

Comment: @paisanco it looks good to me, except that `maxval` should be 255 instead of 256.

Comment: @Mark Shouldn't the magic number be P6 for regular PPM? I agree about 255.

Comment: You need a space between imageHeight and maxval (255). And you shouldn't be closing the file after each line! A newline is needed instead.

Comment: Two other problems, both in findMandelBrot: it should be i < max_iterations and you need to add cr to temp.

Comment: @paisanco P6 is for binary, P3 is for text. Stream output will be text, so P3 is correct. But there are plenty of other problems as pointed out by other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start with debugging is to run the program with simple inputs (e.g. to generate a 8x5 output image), then look at the output.  Since PPM is easily human-readable, you'll see that you get only 8 samples.  That should be a clue that the first row is okay, and there's a problem between that and the second row.  Now zoom in to the row loop and you'll see that you've written `fout.close()` where you meant to emit a newline.

The next thing you'll spot is that all your values come out as zero.  That's a bit harder to diagnose, but if you look in `findMandelBrot` and step through in your mind, you'll go into the `while` loop with `i` equal to 0, and you should spot that the loop never gets entered.

I've re-worked your code a little.  In addition to the bug fixes, I have

- used std::complex rather than re-invent the wheel - look it up in your favourite reference if you're not familiar with it
- assumed you'll do something different with the colours once it's working, or I would have simplified the output to a PGM rather than PPM
- added minimal checking of the reading and writing of files
- included comments to the code explaining my fixes.

Here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;


// Converted to take a std::complex to make the arithmetic clearer
int findMandelBrot(complex<double> c, int max_iterations)
{
    int i = 0;
    complex<double> z = 0;
    // was while(i > max_iterations ...) which would make this always
    // return false
    while (i <= max_iterations && norm(z) < 4.0) {
        z *= z;
        z += c;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

double mapToReal(int x, int imageWidth, double minR, double maxR)
{
    double range = maxR - minR;
    return x * (range / imageWidth) + minR;
}

double mapToImaginary(int y, int imageWidth, double minI, double maxI)
{
    double range = maxI - minI;
    return y * (range / imageWidth) + minI;

}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    int imageWidth, imageHeight, maxN;
    double minR, maxR, minI, maxI;

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Couldn't load input.txt file" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fin >> imageWidth >> imageHeight >> maxN;
    fin >> minR >> maxR >> minI >> maxI;

    // Check whether we managed to read the values
    if (!fin) {
        cerr << "Failed to read input.txt file" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fin.close();

    ofstream fout("output_image.ppm");
    if (!fout) {
        // something went wrong
        cerr << "Couldn't open output file" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fout << "P3" << endl;
    fout << imageWidth << " " << imageHeight;
    fout << " " << "256" << endl;

    for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
            double cr = mapToReal(x, imageWidth, minR, maxR);
            double ci = mapToImaginary(y, imageHeight, minI, maxI);

            int n = findMandelBrot({cr, ci}, maxN);

            int r = (n % 256);
            int g = (n % 256);
            int b = (n % 256);

            fout << r << " " << g << " " << b << " ";
        }
        // was fout.close() - ending the image after first line
        fout << endl;

        // Periodically check for errors
        if (!fout) {
            // something went wrong
            cerr << "Write failed" << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    fout.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That should allow you to continue a little further.